# Categorizing Age According to a Condition in R

Tags: r

I have a big data frame and I would like to categorize the age within the same group according to a condition. Here is an example:

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
    HHID  Sex  Age 
    112   1    14
    112   1    15
    112   2    17
    112   2    19
    113   2    50
    113   2    51
    113   2    51
```

For each (hhid + sex) group, I would like to create a agegrp variable based on the following condition: if there is more than 2 years age difference between each row, categorize them in different groups. Otherwise put them in the same category. Here is what I want:

```
    HHID  Sex  Age Agegrp
    112   1    14   14
    112   1    15   14
    112   2    17   17
    112   2    19   17
    113   2    50   50
    113   2    51   50
    113   2    51   50
```

The data set I have is really large compared to this example. Hence, I am looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a quick `organize` function, then choose `base R`, `dplyr` or `data.table` to implement it. Whichever you prefer:

```
organize <- function(v, threshold=2) v[cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v) > threshold))]

#base (no packages)
df1$Agegrp <- with(df1, ave(Age, HHID, Sex, FUN=organize))

#dplyr
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(HHID, Sex) %>%
  mutate(Agegrp = organize(Age))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, organize(Age), by=.(HHID, Sex)]
```

Comment: Note that `data.table` and `dplyr` have been combined to a single package `dtplyr`.  Just a fun fact :)

Comment: The author has added a `data.table` backend to `dplyr`. Not the same as "combined to a single package". For example, from the github "dtplyr will always be a bit slower than data.table, because it creates copies of objects rather than mutating in place." If you want to use `data.table`, I suggest loading the actual package.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thanks for your help. It worked! :)

Comment: Hello @PierreLafortune , I have another question. I used your code and as I said it worked while working on a small data set (It was including only two years). However, the code did not work properly once I started working on a bigger data set (10 years or more). Do you have any idea about what might cause this problem?

Comment: You would have to detail what "did not work properly" means. You can post another question and link back to this one for reference.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I have changed your organized function little bit and now it works better with a warning. See my answer below.

Comment: The best thing to do is to add to your example the cases that are not being solved. That way we can all see the situations with the problem coming up.

Answer (score 0):

The organize function suggested above by is a good idea. However, cumsum function cannot correctly locate the position of the age if the same age is repeated say for 15 years and change to some other age whose difference with the previous one is more than 2. I wrote the following function to solve this issue:

```
organize = function(v, threshold=2) v[rep.int(which(c(TRUE, diff(v) > threshold)==TRUE), c(diff(which(c(TRUE, diff(v) > threshold)==TRUE)),1))]
```

This function give me the desired output with a warning. The warning is "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". Now working on getting rid of the warning and any help is appreciated.